# Typescript - Store Class Type As Variable In Order to Create Objects From It Or Other Equivalent Functionality

Tags: typescript, class, abstract-class, abstract, factory-method

Preface - I have looked at similar posts to this one on SO, but the answers did not seem applicable.

I have an abstract class with the following method (simplified):

```
playAnimation() {
    let animator =  this.createAnimator(this.animatorData)  
    await animator.animate()
}
```

Create animator has the following definition inside that abstract class:

```
abstract createAnimator(animatorData: Object): Animator
```

A subclass might implement `createAnimator` like this:

```
createAnimator(animatorData: StandardAnimatorData) {
    return new RiverAnimator(animatorData.addMessage, animatorData.assetsDir) 
}
```

or like this:

```
createAnimator(animatorData: StandardAnimatorData) {
    return new BridgeAnimator(animatorData.addMessage, animatorData.assetsDir) 
}
```

As you can see -  both of the sub classes's implementations of `createAnimator` are roughly identical, except for the type of the `Animator` being returned.

Sidenote `BridgeAnimator` and `RiverAnimator` both implement the `Animator` interface, but if the solution requires `Animator` to be an abstract class, I can change it.

Is there a way to move `createAnimator` into the abstract base class?

Ideally the abstract class would have an abstract variable that is the type of the class that `createAnimator` should return. Subclasses would merely implement that variable. Then `createAnimator` would use that variable to return the proper type of `Animator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this (I made one big code snippet so I can verify that everything compiles):

```
interface Animator {
  animate(): Promise<void>;
}

class RiverAnimator implements Animator {
  async animate() { }
  constructor(addMessage: unknown, assetsDir: unknown) { }
}
class BridgeAnimator implements Animator {
  async animate() { }
  constructor(addMessage: unknown, assetsDir: unknown) { }
}

interface StandardAnimatorData {
  addMessage: unknown;
  assetsDir: unknown;
}

// Common interface for the constructor functions RiverAnimator and BridgeAnimator 
interface AnimatorConstructor {
  new(addMessage: unknown, assetsDir: unknown): Animator;
}

abstract class AbstractOuterClass {
  abstract animatorConstructor: AnimatorConstructor;
  animatorData: StandardAnimatorData;
  createAnimator(data: StandardAnimatorData) {
    return new this.animatorConstructor(data.addMessage, data.assetsDir);
  } 
  async playAnimation() {
    let animator = this.createAnimator(this.animatorData);
    await animator.animate();
  }
}

class SubOuterClass1 extends AbstractOuterClass {
  animatorConstructor = RiverAnimator;
}

class SubOuterClass2 extends AbstractOuterClass {
  animatorConstructor = BridgeAnimator;
}
```

But it's not clear to me that this is any better than implementing `createAnimator` in `SubOuterClass1` and `SubOuterClass2`.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use the power of generics:

declaration:

```js
createAnimator<T extends Animator>(
    type: { new(addMessage: unknown, assetDir: unknown): T }, 
    animatorData: StandardAnimatorData
): T {
    return new type(animatorData.addMessage, animatorData.assetDir);
}
```

invocation:

```js
let animator = this.createAnimator(BridgeAnimator, animatorData);
await animator.animate();
```